# From where comes Opacity[0.3] in PointLegend?

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, legending

In `PointLegend` we have (checked with versions 10.4.1 and 11.0.0) `EdgeForm[Opacity[0.3]]` by default applied to `LegendMarkers`:

```
PointLegend[{Directive[Blue, EdgeForm[{Red, Thickness[.05]}]]}, {"label1"}, 
 LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[Disk[]]}, LegendMarkerSize -> 70]

Cases[ToBoxes[%], GraphicsBox[p_, _] /; ! FreeQ[p, DiskBox], Infinity]

RawBoxes@%
```

> [image: legend]
>
> ```
> GraphicsBox[DiskBox[{0, 0}], {DefaultBaseStyle -> {"Graphics", {AbsolutePointSize[6]}, 
>     Directive[PointSize[0.5], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
>      EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.3], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Thickness[0.257143]]]]}}]
> ```
>
> [image]

As one can see from the above, the edge of the disk has `Opacity[0.3]` which was not specified in the original `PointLegend` expression but is somehow introduced during conversion into boxes.

I have two questions:

1. **From where comes `Opacity[0.3]`?**
2. **How to disable it?**

---

I know that one workaround is to put `EdgeForm[Opacity[1]]` directly into every of the `LegendMarkers`:

```
LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Opacity[1]], Disk[]}]}
```

but I would like to disable this "feature" completely.

Comment: No `Opacity` in version 9. Either a bug or a bad default design decision. Probably an untested special case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opacity comes from this symbol:

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle

(* EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.3], GrayLevel[0]]] *)
```

You can redefine it, e.g.

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle = EdgeForm[Black]
```